# android autocomplete settext in two lines

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am trying to setText("long pile of text") of my AutoCompleteTextView with a line separator. When I insert the text it makes it with horizontal scroll. I want to make it in two lines:

"long pile

of text"

\n\r is working fine for the dropdownlist, but when i click the item, it moves it to the AutoCompleteTextView for which \r\n doesn't work

Things i have tried and failed with:

inserting \n, \r\n, System getProperty("line.separator"), in the string

setting values for autocomplete like

```
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="2"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

this is mine AutoCompleteTextView

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtxt_ticket_code"
    android:background="@drawable/round_border_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Upisi rutu"
    android:lines="2"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_main"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_light"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this  **android:inputType="textMultiLine"**

Finally ,

```
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:dropDownHeight="fill_parent"
         android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
```

I hope it will helps you

Comment: Thank you very very much...not sure how i missed this one ( *embarrassed ) ...  it was the android:inputType="textMultiLine"